# TextBox only in uppercase

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want the `TextBox` only be in uppercase. in windows phone it doesn't has `CharacterCasing`, only solution I can think of is:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   textBox.Text = textBox.Text.ToUpper();
}
```

It will do the process each time user presses a key which is not good. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no better way than tracking `TextChanged`. However, your implementation is flawed because it doesn't account for the fact that the user might change the caret position.

Instead, you should use this:

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox currentContainer = ((TextBox)sender);
    int caretPosition = currentContainer.SelectionStart;

    currentContainer.Text = currentContainer.Text.ToUpper();
    currentContainer.SelectionStart = caretPosition++;
}
```

Comment: not working in windows 10 mobile :( - every second letter back geoes to position 0 + 1

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively you can set the `CharacterCasing` to `Upper` in the textbox property.

Comment: That isn't available too :)

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```
    private void txtCode_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.KeyChar = char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and found a solution.

Step 1 : Make TextBox ReadOnly.

Step 2  : Capture any key pressed.

Check if the textbox that we want has the focus.If true submit the character to the textbox but in uppercase.

Done!

Comment: this means more work, cause user can insert a character anywhere in text

Comment: And i said that you should check if the textbox that we want has focus!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use text box leave event

it will fire when textbox is not active In Simple Words It Will occur when you are leaving TextBox to any other thing

```
private void textBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textBox.Text = textBox.Text.ToUpper();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this too, it works for me

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text.ToUpper();

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a property in the component named "CharacterCasing", set it to "Upper" and that's all you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
textBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
```